# UnityEngine.Plane - Incorrect distance

Tags: geometry, unity-game-engine

I create a plane object:

```
Plane p = new Plane(
    new Vector3(1, 0, 0),
    new Vector3(10, 0, 0));
```

I expected this result:

```
p.normal == new Vector3(1, 0, 0)
p.distance == 10
```

However when I debug my code, I see that the result of `p.distance` is -10 instead of 10.

The `Plane.distance` comment says "Distance from the origin to the plane.". So from origin to the plane it must be 10 distance. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: If you use the second parameter just for distance, then you should probably go for `public Plane(Vector3 inNormal, float distance)`. Otherwise the normal might be the wrong way around so you actually create the plane on the other side. Inverse the direction of the normal in this case.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are right.

Follow some links to help the discussion.

[Plane class](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Plane.html)

[Plane equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Plane.html)

In you your case your plane equation is x+10=0. Therefore,with d=10, D=10/sqrt(sqr(1))= 10